# Nested classes, inheritance and shared pointers in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, nested, shared-ptr

The program below fails, obviously, in the *return* expression:

```
#include <memory>

class Base {
    public:

        class Nested {
            public:
                int c;
        };
};

class A : public Base {
    public:

        class Nested : public Base::Nested {
            public:
                int c = 1;
        };
};

class B : public Base {
    public:

        class Nested : public Base::Nested {
            public:
                int c = 2;
        };
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Base> X = std::make_shared<A>();

    return X::Nested.c;
};
```

How can I get *Nested.c* value of X?

In other words, I have one base class (*Base*) and two derived classes (*A* and *B*). Each derived class has a nested class (*Nested*). I want to called *Nested.c* from an instance *X*, which is dynamically selected as one of the derived classes.

Comment: You don't have any instances of any `Nested`-class. None of those classes will automatically contain an instance of `Nested`. `X` is an empty class with no members at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just a misconception about nested classes. A Nested class does *not* magically add members to it's parent class. You need to do that manually, for example:

```
class Base {
  public:

    class Nested {
        public:
            int c;
    };

    Nested nested; // member of nested class Base::Nested.
};
```

Keep in mind that `Base::Nested`, `A::Nested` and `B::Nested` are all different classes. Allthough they look similiar they are not related at all.

---

Maybe the following is what you want:

```
#include <memory>

class Base {
private:
    class Nested {
        public:
            int c;
    };

    Nested nested; // member of nested class Base::Nested.
 public:
  virtual int getC() const { return this->nested.c; }
};

class A : public Base {
private:
    class Nested {
        public:
            int c = 1;
    };

    Nested nested; // member of nested class A::Nested.
 public:
  int getC() const override { return this->nested.c; }
};

class B : public Base {
private:
    class Nested {
        public:
            int c = 2;
    };

    Nested nested; // member of nested class B::Nested.
 public:
  int getC() const override { return this->nested.c; }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Base> X = std::make_shared<B>();
    return (*X).getC();
};
```

Each class has it's own member of it's own nested class and returns `c` with a virtual getter.

Comment: This solution doesn't return 1, using `X->nested.c`. How should I modify the code to obtain it?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. Do you understand what's wrong with your approach in the first place? What is your goal?

Comment: I understand the problem, but don't find the solution. I have one Base class and two derived classes. Each derived class has a nested class Nested. I want to called Nested.c from an instance X, which is dynamically selected as one of the derived classes.

Comment: @Medicalphysicist You could use a virtual getter for `c`. Then `A` and `B` would contain their own instance of `A::Nested` and `B::Nested` respectively and return the appropriate value.